# Project branch showing both in the project and separately

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a project called **project**.
It has 3 branches: **branch1**, **branch2** and **master**.

I edited a file manually on **branch2** (meaning on the web interface directly: I know it is not a good practice)

Everything is ok. But now whenever I log in to the web interface, I see **branch2** displayed both inside project and as a standalone project.

This means I see:

```
project-branch2 // Notice how its name is displayed
project // branch2 is listed among the branches here
```

How can I remove **project-branch2** from the web interface without removing **branch2** from **project** ?

Comment: What is the "web interface"? How did you edit that file? Does branch2 exist before editing that file?

Comment: 1. Web interface = browser. 2. Yes, **branch2** existed before I edited one of its fiels via the browser

Comment: If 'project' and 'project-branch2' isn't related why not just [delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24032232) the later one.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it just forked your project. You can probably delete it without it affecting the original project. You can usually do this in the project specific settings.

You may want to verify this by

```
git fetch --all     #update
git branch -a       #list all branches
```

If you see project-branch2 as a branch:

```
git push origin --delete origin/project-branch2
```

Comment: Yes, it should work that way but I forget to mention I am not the owner of that project, so all the branches are protected

Comment: Did you make changes logged in as you or as the project manager? If as your user, then you don't need to worry about deleting anything that you are not supposed to, so you can safely delete that extraneous (forked) project from its settings menu. Are you using github, bitbucket, gitlab, or something else?

Comment: In the project settings there is no option to delete it because I do not own it. Gitlab

Comment: So here is how I understand it.  You attempted to edit a branch that you did not have permission to edit.  Instead of adopting your commit into the project, because the branch is protected, it forked the project into a new repository "project-branch2" (probably a partial copy of the repository) which you should have permission over. You still do not have permission over the repository "project", but because you forked the project, you have permission over this fork:
To delete you need to go to advanced settings.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24032232/how-to-remove-a-gitlab-project